# Mac stuck in safe boot

Tags: terminal, hard-drive, restart

I accidentally did a hard reset on my mac by doing contorl+c when my mac was booting up. I typed `/sbin/fsck -fy` because it was supposed to fix my Mac so that it is no longer stuck in safe boot. It said to type `reboot`, but now my Mac won't start outside of recovery mode. I need help trying to recover data and starting the computer.

Comment: I'm not fully understanding you. You will not lose any files by simply booting with keys held down. You would need to format the drive or have drive failure to lose data.

Comment: so lets presume drive failure - & hope we have a backup...

Comment: I don't have a back up

Comment: So you ran `fsck` and told it to automatically fix corruption on the drive (`-y` option) and the machine no longer boots. Are you familiar with UNIX in general? Try booting into the recovery partition and opening Terminal from the menu. Then, type `cd Volumes/YOURDRIVENAME/Users/YOURNAME` and then `ls`. Are you able to `cd` into your drive? Is your home directory intact?

Comment: If you are unable to `cd` into your home directory, post the output of `ls /Volumes` from the recovery partition Terminal.

Comment: .Trashes             Image Volume
BOOTCAMP.      OS X Base System

Answer (score -1):

Running the command   `/sbin/fsck –fy`   initiates a file system consistency check utility which should scan your system and attempt to repair any issues, this scan is documented to take approximately 15 minutes and should not be interrupted.

---

You should restart your computer, press the power button, and then immediately press and hold the  <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>  keys as the computer starts up.  This will boot you into Single-user mode and you should see white text on the screen.  Now run the `fsck` utility and wait.

When it's done it should prompt you with the message "File System was modified" or "No problems were found".  If you see the first message, you should repeat the entire process over and over again until you receive the "No problems were found" message.  This may take 3 or more times of repeating the process.

---

If after 5 times you still do not get the No problems were found prompt then your last hope is to attempt a Disk Repair.

Find a OSX install disc, and insert it, restart, holding down the  <kbd>C</kbd>  key to boot to the disc.  Once it starts up, navigate to the Disk Utility application which will be found in one of the drop down menu's along the top of the window.

Within the Disk Utility application select your drive and run the Repair Disk command.  Run it repeatedly until it responds that no errors needed to be repaired.

If it still doesn't work, buy a new hard-drive.

Comment: Consider an edit to allow for booting into Recovery mode is the OP has no other bootable media?

Comment: Not sure I'm clear on the issue then.. sorry.  If he can boot to recovery mode he can still access both terminal and disk utility from the menu options.

Comment: What exactly do you think Disk Utility does?